# Remove directive dynamically

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an directive (my-header) to make the header area fix while page scrolling up. I want to remove the directive on a button click.

```
<div class="partialInner" id="fixedHeader" my-header>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddingZero">
        <ng-include src="'topNavi.html'"> </ng-include>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddingZero">
        <ng-include src="'middle.html'"> </ng-include>
      </div>
</div>
```

Remove

when click on the myBtn I want to take the "my-header" attribute out of my code

Appreciate any anwser

Answer (score 0):

Execute this code when your button is pressed

```
$document.getElementById("fixedHeader").removeAttribute("my-header");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `ng-show` or `ng-if`.

```
<div class="partialInner" id="fixedHeader" my-header ng-if="isHeader" ng-init="isHeader = true">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddingZero">
        <ng-include src="'topNavi.html'"> </ng-include>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 paddingZero">
        <ng-include src="'middle.html'"> </ng-include>
      </div> 
</div>
```

And in your button click, you can make `isHeader` to `false`.

```
<button ng-click="isHeader = false"> Hide header </button>
```

Comment: Please use comments to as questions

Comment: Thank you for the above code. But I want to remove only the my-header part from the code. I tried removeAttribute() as well. But its not working